# ES6: How to call a class function from a callback function

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, es6-class

I have a class and in the init method I'm setting up a click event, and inside that event I want to call a method on the class and I can't figure out how to do it or if it's even possible. Here's code that shows the structure of what I'm trying. in the classes init() function, after the ajax returns I'm setting up a click event, and in that callback I want to call the class's classFn() function. I've tried binding this, I've tried self = this and binding that, arrow functions (which I didn't expect to work but figured I'd give it a try), etc.

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
   this.a = '';
  }

  init() {
    ....
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $(mySelector).click(function() {
        classFn();
      });
    });
  }

  classFn() {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: "I want to call a method on the class" In your code `classFn` is an instance method, not a class method. Can you clarify?

Comment: another possibility is to assign "this" to a new variable that wont change.. `var self = this;` then inside the callback use `self.myFunct();`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`function` changes the meaning of `this`. One way to fix the problem is to use `bind`. However, you'd have to use it twice, because you have two layers of `function`. A simple way to solve it is to use arrow functions, which do not change `this`:

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
   this.a = '';
  }

  init() {
    ....
    $.getJSON(url, (data) => {
      $(mySelector).click(() => {
        this.classFn();
      });
    });
  }

  classFn() {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: The arrow functions don't work. I put bind in multiple places and that works. That's what I was missing: multiple binds. Once it was working, I wanted to start from the inside out converting them to arrow functions. But on the first one it fails. In the event callback, this is still bound to the clicked element. Is it possible that when an arrow function is used as a function argument that the "lexically surrounding code" may not be what we think it is?

I also figured out that making the method static and calling it with MyClass.classFn() will work as well.

Comment: @kombat Ah, no it's nothing to do with "lexically surrounding code". It is because jQuery makes sure to `bind` the function you give as a callback, so that `this` (or `$(this)`) refer to the element. See e.g. https://api.jquery.com/click/ (the examples section at the bottom) My bad.

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the callback function and call like `this.classFn()`. You could either use `.bind` or `arrow function`

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
   this.a = '';
   this.init = this.init.bind(this);
  }

  init() {
    ....
    $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
      $(mySelector).click(function() {
        this.classFn();
      }.bind(this));
    }.bind(this));
  }

  classFn() {
    ....
  }
}
```

or

```
class MyClass {
  constructor() {
   this.a = '';
  }

  init = ()  => {   // class fields are stage-2 proposal with es6
    ....
    $.getJSON(url,(data) =>  {
      $(mySelector).click(()  => {
        this.classFn();
      });
    });
  }

  classFn() {
    ....
  }
}
```

Comment: @Occam'sRazor, Well I saw it when I was editing my answer